# How do I use the same parameter more than once?

Tags: php, string-formatting, printf

I know about `sprintf()`, but how can I use the same parameter more than once?

If I use the following code, I get an error about using few parameters.

```php
sprintf("blabla %s 11111 %s", "test");
```

I want to replace `%s` with `"test"` twice.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `%$` numbered placeholder notation:

```
sprintf('blabla %1$s 11111 %1$s', "test");
```

Here, both occurrences of `%1$s` will be replaced with `"test"`. There is more on this in the [`sprintf()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Comment: @kusanagi: Yeah I messed up, replace the double quotes with single quotes (or use `%1\$s` but that's ugly).

Answer (score 4):

This is called "Argument swapping" and documented in example #3 here: http://php.net/sprintf
Use `"%1$s"`, to use argument 1, you can use this multiple times within your format string, as shown in Example #4 of php online documentation.